# Do I need Browserify for a TypeScript-powered project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on a pet project to try out TypeScript and all its nice features.

TypeScript supports modules from the box and [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) can concatenate all files into one. I used Browserify in my JavaScript projects before and it served perfectly to modularize my apps.

Now I wonder if I can do things without it in the TypeScript world or if it still can fill gaps.

Comment: a quick google search for "typescript with browserify" turns up plenty of examples showing their use together.....

Comment: You may want to take a look also at the [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/). It could be a better [option](http://webpack.github.io/docs/comparison.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I wonder if I can do things without it in the TypeScript world or if it still can fill gaps.

You cannot use `--out` and `--module` together. I highly recommend you use `--module commonjs` ([reasons](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)). This would mean you would need to use something like browserify.

Comment: Why would you recommend using commonjs instead of amd which is a module format that works natively in browsers?

Comment: For consistency and needless future migration to `umd` ;)

Comment: As mentioned when you are using modules you typescript compile can't concatenate src files for you. You need to use browserify or webpack or some other build tool that will traverse depndency tree of your modules and create a bundle.